# Accessing elements in namespace defined in header file

Tags: c++, function, makefile, namespaces, header-files

I am trying to access variables and functions defined in a namespace in a header file. However, I get the error: `xor.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to "the function in header file" collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. It seems to me that the compilation steps are OK after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), and also because I can access variables in this header file, but calling the function returns the error mentioned above. My question is: How can I access those functions in the namespace from my main.cpp ? What am I doing wrong ?

The case with a class is clear to me, but here I don't understand because I am not supposed to create an object, so just calling the namespace in front should be OK (?).

### Edit

After changes suggested by Maestro, I have updated the code the following way, but it still doesn't work. The error I get is the same. If I define `using NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob = 6.7;` I get the error: `xor.cpp:127:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token`

**Main c++**

```
#include "experiments.h"
#include "neat.h"
#include <cstring>

int main(){

  const char *the_string = "test.ne";
  bool bool_disp = true;
  NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob;
  trait_param_mut_prob = 6.7;
  NEAT::load_neat_params(the_string ,bool_disp);
  std::cout << NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**neat.h**

```
    #ifndef _NERO_NEAT_H_
    #define _NERO_NEAT_H_
    
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstring>
    
    namespace NEAT {
        extern double trait_param_mut_prob;
        bool load_neat_params(const char *filename, bool output = false); //defined HERE 
    
    }
    #endif
```

**neat.cpp**

```
#include "neat.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

double NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob = 0;

bool NEAT::load_neat_params(const char *filename, bool output) { 
                    //prints some stuff
                    return false;
                    };
```

**Makefile**

```
neat.o: neat.cpp neat.h
        g++ -c neat.cpp
```

Comment: Where is the `#endif` in header?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_NERO_NEAT_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: @Maestro indeed I forgot to copy the #endif in the post, but it is in the code

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the remark. What I am actually trying to do here is to modify a package which I downloaded, so there is no problem with those _NERO_NEAT_H_

Comment: @Joachim — downloading a file doesn’t exempt it from the rules. That identifier is reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are breaking the "ODR rule" (One-Definition-Rule): you've defined `trait_param_mut_prob` and `load_neat_params` twice once in source file `neat.cpp` and second in `main.cpp` so simply remove those lines from main.cpp:

```
//double NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob; //NEAT is the namespace 
//bool NEAT::load_neat_params(const char* filename, bool output); //function defined in the namespace
```

- Add `#endif` in you header `neat.h`.
- to make your function and variable available in main just use `using` or fully-qualify the call because as I've seen you intend to re-declare them in main to avoid fully qualifying them: in main:

  ```
  int main()
  {

      using NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob;
      using NEAT::load_neat_params;

      const char* the_string = "test.ne";
      bool bool_disp = true;
      trait_param_mut_prob = 6.7;//works perfectly 
      load_neat_params(the_string, bool_disp);
      // or fully-qualify:

      //NEAT::load_neat_params(the_string, bool_disp);
      //NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob = 6.7;//works perfectly 
  }
  ```
- Also it is erroneous that your function `load_neat_params` doesn't return a `bool` value. So make it either return `true` or `false`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have tried both options. Either fully qualifying or with using, I still get the same error: `g++ xor.cpp
/tmp/cccl2MH9.o: In function main:
xor.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob'
xor.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to NEAT::load_neat_params(char const*, bool)
xor.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status `. I will update the code

Comment: Actually, only by calling the following way: `using NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob = 6.7` I get `xor.cpp:127:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token` which, again I don't understand why

Comment: No! Remove assignment: `= 6.7` so it becomes: `using NEAT::trait_param_mut_prob;`.

Comment: Excuse the stupid question, but what do you mean exactly by adding the source to the project ? It is compiled with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What compiler are using? Your program works fine with me.

Comment: I'm using g++, I compile first with the makefile and then compile the main cpp with the simple command `g++ xor.cpp`. I tried removing the `=6.7` as you mentioned but still get the same error mentioned above

Comment: Are you specifying `C++11`?

Comment: No but I have tried with the `-std=c++11` but it didn't change anything. Also I have updaetd the code removing `=6.7` in the `using`

Comment: First I compile with the command `make` in the terminal and then execute with the exact command `g++ -std=c++11 xor.cpp`. Also all the files are in the same folder

Comment: where is `neat.cpp`?

Comment: `neat.cpp`is in the makefile in order to get the object file `neat.o`, if my understanding is correct

Comment: Try it without make file from a terminal.

Comment: Try this from terminal: `g++ neat.cpp main.cpp -o prog`.

Comment: I am so sorry. Please google on how to set your makefile. Accept as an answer if it helps.

Comment: Indeed there must be a problem there. Still, I have always done this for classes and never had problems. Could you perhaps give me a hint about where is the problem in the makefile ?

Comment: Excuse me. now I am not on gcc but i'm using MSVC.

Comment: You are welcome! Happy for having it worked for you!